# MSBuild Item order when using wildcards

Tags: msbuild

When creating MSBuild Items from files using wildcards, such as,

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Scripts>$(ScriptsDirectory)\**\*.sql</Scripts>
</ItemGroup>
```

the files *seem* to always be sorted alphabetically by path.

However, is this sort order guaranteed - can I rely on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, MSBuild will always sort alphabetically by path, in order to guarantee repeatability.  (This is covered in my new book, "MSBuild Trickery")

Comment: @Brian Kretzler: any reference where is this documented? I've alos interested in this question but have not found anything regarding order of items.

Comment: I'm leary of getting downvoted for self-promotion, but since you've asked, just type "MSBuild Trickery" into any search engine -- it's on page 136

Comment: @BrianKretzler we don't want to see self promotion, but if you have an Information source - like your book - you could simply say: *You may find more information about this topic in "MSBuild Trickery" Page 136, which is easily found with any search engine.* I would not see any problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to sort an ItemGroup of files based on the actual filename, not the full path. So I wrote an MSBuild task to do this, hope it helps...

[MSBuild sort itemgroup of files by filename](http://jpadda.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/sort-2-dimensional-jagged-array-csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Some time back I came across an [oddity](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/04/msbuild-sort-itemgroup.html) transitioning from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010 with the ordering of an ItemGroup that was creating using a wildcard. File names that started with an underscore character '_' went from being first in the results to last.

At the time I resolved this using the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/). This provides a TaskAction to explicitly sort an ItemGroup.

E.g.

```
<!-- Sort an ItemGroup alphabetically -->  
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.MsBuildHelper TaskAction="Sort" InputItems1="@(MainDataFiles)">  
    <Output TaskParameter="OutputItems" ItemName="sorted"/>  
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.MsBuildHelper>  
<Message Text="Sorted Items: %(sorted.Identity)"/>
```